# An error while loading a model in codeigniter hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, hmvc

I load a model in a controller. But I have this error:

`Message: Undefined property: Captcha::$captcha_model`

And also this message:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function captcha_insert() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-framework\application\modules\captcha\controllers\captcha.php on line 31`

Everything seems true!

Controller:

```
$time = $captcha['time'];
$ip_address = $this->input->ip_address();
$word = $captcha['word'];
$this->load->model('captcha/captcha_model');
$value = $this->captcha_model->captcha_insert($time, $ip_address, $word);
```

model:

```
class Captcha_model extends CI_model {


 public function captcha_insert($time, $ip_address, $word){

    $query = $this->db->query("insert into captcha
                                (time, ip_address, word)
                                values(?, ?, ?)",
                                array($time, $ip_address, $word));
    if ($query)
        return true;
 }


}
```

What's wrong?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Change the name of model and then try may be it will work. .

Comment: Make sure the filename of your model is `Captcha_model.php` and is located inside `application/model/captcha/`

Comment: @AnilBaweja Thank you, but it didn't work :)

Comment: @AdrienXL This is hmvc, not mvc. `captcha_model.php` is loacated in `application/modules/captcha/models`. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Right hmvc, my bad. But that doesn't change the fact that the model filename should be Ucfirst. :)

Comment: I found the problem. It works when I run module directly. But when I call back that module in a controller this happens. I am going to search.

Comment: @AdrienXL Damn it :D I found the problem. Not only in `module/controller` , But also in base `controller` I have to extend `MX` not `CI`. Thank you guys.

Comment: Please write your solution in a new answer and accept it. Otherwise everybody will see it as not solved in the forums.

Comment: @AdrienXL That's ok. I am going to do this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71400/discussion-between-vahid-najafi-and-adrienxl).

Comment: @AdrienXL stackoverflow doesn't let me accept my own answer in less than 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$time = $captcha['time'];
$ip_address = $this->input->ip_address();
$word = $captcha['word'];
$this->load->model('captcha_model/captcha_insert');
$value = $this->captcha_model->captcha_insert($time, $ip_address, $word);
```